# Unable to center :after and :before horizontally and vertically

Tags: css

Whenever I need to position something so it's vertical and/or horizontally I'd normally resort to flexbox, and if that's not the solution I `position: absolute` with `top:50%;` and/or `left:50%;` with `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);`. I tried this with the following code, but I did not get such results.

**HTML**

```css
.plus-minus-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;

  &:before,
  &:after{
    background: white;
    content: '';
    height: 5px;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 21px;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transition: transform 500ms ease;
  }

  &:after {
    transform-origin: center;
  }

  &.collapsed {
    &:after {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }

    &:before {
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
    <div class="plus-minus-toggle collapsed"></div>
```

I am unsure about how to achieve this, I even tried wrapping the `div` in a parent `div` and applying the positioning css there, but no luck, it was the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your transforms are overriding one another and need to be combined.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.plus-minus-toggle').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('collapsed');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}
.plus-minus-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
}
.plus-minus-toggle:before,
.plus-minus-toggle:after {
  background: white;
  content: '';
  height: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 21px;
  transition: transform 500ms ease;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.plus-minus-toggle:after {
  transform-origin: center;
}
.plus-minus-toggle.collapsed:after {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
}
.plus-minus-toggle.collapsed:before {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="plus-minus-toggle collapsed"></div>
```

Comment: I updated your answer. I noticed when I clicked on the icon it wasn't centered, so for `.plus-minus-toggle:before, .plus-minus-toggle:after` I added `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);`.

Comment: @DarrenBachan the edit you made applied transform to the pseudo elements, and that same transform is being applied to the pseudo elements individually, so it's redundant. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the other lines of css target `.plus-minus-toggle.collapsed:after` and `.plus-minus-toggle.collapsed:before` it has `.collapsed` on it, the line of css I added doesn't have `.collapsed`.